# Permission Denied error calling external service from appengine go

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm getting a permission denied error when I make a call to another web service from within my go code.

part of the handler code on my server side go program:

```
client := http.Client{}
if resp, err := client.Get("http://api.wipmania.com/" + r.RemoteAddr); err != nil {
    c.Errorf("Error getting location from ip: %s", err.Error())
}
```

From the logs:

```
Error getting location from ip: Get http://api.wipmania.com/30.30.30.30: permission denied
```

I saw a similar qn [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199694/ajax-error-permission-denied).  Still unable to figure it out.  Can you please tell me what is the right way to do this and if any permissions have to be set on the appengine console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Engine applications can communicate with other applications and can access other resources on the web by fetching URLs. An app can use the [URL Fetch service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/urlfetch/overview) to issue HTTP and HTTPS requests and receive responses.

Try:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "appengine"
    "appengine/urlfetch"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    client := urlfetch.Client(c)
    if resp, err := client.Get("http://api.wipmania.com/" + r.RemoteAddr); err != nil {
        c.Errorf("Error getting location from ip: %s", err.Error())
    }
    // ...
}
```